# Where to deploy a Sinatra application?

Tags: web-applications, deployment, sinatra, paas

What are the possibilities?
I know of [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/), but I am not happy with it.
I am aware of [Engineyard](http://www.engineyard.com/). 
Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider one of the new breed Open PaaS (Such as CloudFoundry, OpenShift & Cloudify), these PaaS solutions as opposed to Heruko or EngineYard allow you to on board your own Sinatra application on any cloud.

[Cloudify](http://www.cloudifysource.org) (which I'm one of its contributors) can on board Sinatra on any cloud, using a simple groovy based DSL recipes.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide a link for reference. The main reason for this is that links go stale and thus your answer might not have any value in the future when the link is broken. Note, many (most) sites are under copyright, so wholesale copying content from the linked page into the answer is not OK either. Your best option is to write up an answer of your own, and then if necessary, add the link to that site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have not tried it yet, VMWare's [CloudFoundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com) initiative supports Sinatra. Bonus points for begin a free service, for the time being (while they are in beta).

Comment: I think I will have a look at dotcloud. It looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There is AlwaysData (https://www.alwaysdata.com/) where I just have a free account but don't use it for Ruby.

They offer Ruby 1.9.2 and Passenger is available on demand.